# Javascript: instance vars and static methods; is this ok in terms of memory?

Tags: javascript, memory-management

```
if (typeof Object.create4 !== 'function') {
    Object.create4 = function (t) {
        var F, f, i, ins = {}, sta = {};

        for(i in t){
            // method: static, means will only exists 1, so is less memory intensive
            if(typeof t[i] === 'function'){
                sta[i] = t[i];
            }
            // vars: instance, means 1 for each object, so is more memory intensive
            else{
                ins[i] = t[i];
            }
        }

        // make a copy of the instances
        ins = jQuery.extend(true, {}, ins);


        F = function() {}
        F.prototype = sta;
        f = new F();

        // assign instances to the instance
        for(i in ins){
            f[i] = ins[i];
        }
        return f;
    };
}

var Vehicle4 = (function(){
    var that = {}

    that.instanceVar = {hey: 1}
    that.staticMethod = function(){
        console.log(this.instanceVar);
    }
    return that;
}())

var v31 = Object.create4(Vehicle4);
var v32 = Object.create4(Vehicle4);

v31.instanceVar.hey = 2;
v31.staticMethod();
v32.staticMethod();
```

is this ok in terms of memory?
I mean:
in 1000 objects instanced there will be:

1*staticMethod
1000*instanceVar

is this efficient? I want to note that the instanceVar will be modified in each object so a signle object is not enought.

and might have any memory leaks?

```
var inherit = function(P, C) {
    return jQuery.extend(true, {}, P, C);
}

var Vehicle = function() {}
Vehicle.prototype = {
    init: function(){
        this.instanceVar = {hey: 1}
    },
    staticMethod: function() {
        console.log(this.instanceMember);
    },
    staticMethod3: function() {
        console.log(this.instanceMember);
    }
}

var SuperVehicle = function() {}
SuperVehicle.prototype = inherit(Vehicle.prototype, {
    init: function(){
        this.super.init.call(this);
        this.instanceVar2 = {hey: 1}
    },
    staticMethod: function() {
        console.log(this.instanceVar.hey);
        console.log(this.instanceVar2.hey);
    },
    staticMethod2: function() {
        console.log(this.instanceVar.hey);
        console.log(this.instanceVar2.hey);
    }
});
SuperVehicle.prototype.super = Vehicle.prototype;

var s = new SuperVehicle();
s.init();
s.staticMethod();
s.staticMethod2();
s.staticMethod3();
```

Comment: It may or may not be efficient _for what you're doing_, but we won't really know until you try it. Optimize later when you've measured a problem.

Comment: Yeah, it's silly to try learn the right way to do things before you start. Much better to try to fix them after you're knee deep in crud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you for sure that it is correct and you won't have memory leaks, but concerning the efficiency, i have some doubts.
Firstly, your static members aren't quite static... they are just added to the prototypic chain of the object. The whole prototype inheritance system relies on the fact that every object inherits it's fathers prototype recursively.

So, if you add a property to the primitive Object , such as:

```
Object.prototype.toString = function(){console.log("I am a primitive object");}
```

all of the object in your window would inherit this function and they would be "primitive" :)).

You could call this a "static" method only if you consider the fact that it is loaded in the memory only once and not for every instance, but you cannot consider it static, because it interacts with the current instance of the object (in other object oriented languages, if you put the "this" keyword inside a static method, it throws an exception)

But I don't see the point of all that in your example.

In your example, you pin the "static" methods into the prototype of the object you want to create, but you recreate the prototype for each object instance. If you create 2 or more instances of the same "class", they won't share the prototype but they will each have identical ones.

It's right there:

```
F = function() {};
F.prototype = sta;
f = new F();
```

Every time you create vehicles with this method:

```
var myVehicle = Object.create4(Vehicle4);
var anotherVehicle = Object.create4(Vehicle4);
```

You create prototypes for each instance, witch kind of defeats the purpose of the prototypic inheritance.

I would definitely go for the classic method of creating objects (with the "new" operator) :

```
var Vehicle = function(val){this.instanceMember = val;}  
Vehicle.prototype = {   
    "staticMethod": function(){console.log(this.instanceMember);}   
}    
var v1 = new Vehicle("foo");  
var v2 = new Vehicle("bar");
```

This way you can easily change the staticMethod and affect all Vehicle instances:

```
Vehicle.prototype.staticMethod = function(){  
    console.log(arguments[0] || this.instanceMember);  
};
```

while in your example if you change the staticMethod, the changes will be applied only to the instances constructed after the change occurred.
This being said, in this case, the old classic way of creating objects with "static" members is by far more efficient.

P.S. : Sorry if i got carried away :)

Comment: I'm kind of new in javascript prototypical inheritance and code reuse, so I try to catch some "right" and "efficient" way to build my app. Yes for me static in this case means that is only loaded once in the memory. And change a static property is not really needed. In my approach if I inherit from an object will find faster the methods and vars because everything is in this prototype chain, while the drawback is that will take more time to instance/create a new object.I can even cache every object created. I'm I right about this?I will post more things. And in your case how would you inherit?

Comment: Now I see Im wrong. I did some benchs and yours is way faster xD so I will go your way, is about x30 faster with no inheritance, and x20 with inheritance. So in my case, where I need a lot of objects that's the way! thanks

Comment: ps and how do I get instance variables from a parent object to a child?

Comment: well,the inheritage part is quite simple: you just define the superClass as the prototype for your object.       
ex: var superClass = function(){};
var subClass = function(){}; 
console.log(subClassInstance.name);
superClass.prototype.name = "i'm the superclass";   
subClass.prototype = new superClass();
var subClassInstance = new subClass();

Comment: you'll see that the subClassItem's name is the same as in superCLass.
To answer your second question, when an object inherits another,it inherits it's model,it's class... it's prototype, not it's instance. You can't naturally pass vars from an instance of a superClass to an instance of a subClass